# In Java, how does one get the class implementing an interface from within the interface?

Tags: java, reflection, interface

I have this interface

```
public interface Deserializable{
    static <T> T deserialize(byte[] bytes) {
        ReflectionDeserializer rd = new ReflectionDeserializer();
        return rd.Deserialize(bytes);
    }
}
```

There is a problem in that ReflectionDeserializer needs a class instance in its constructor. In this case, the class I want to pass in is the class of whatever class the `implements` statement is on, so if I have  `public class Cat implements Deserializable`,  I want the interface to put `Cat.class` into the constructor.

How do I do this?

Comment: That `deserialize` method is `static`, and is therefore associated with the interface itself, not an instance of an implementing class. Are you sure it makes sense for this method to be `static`?

Comment: Or maybe what you want is `static <T> T deserialize(Class<T> type, byte[] bytes)`?

Comment: @Slaw correct, and for my use case, static is a requirement.  It should be able to be overridden by instances of an implementing class.

Comment: Multiple classes can implement an interface. Options include: A) Add a `deserialize()` argument of type Class<T> or B) get the actual type from the byte stream.

Comment: @AndyThomas yes, which is why I use reflection in my code instead of building dependencies..

Comment: @tuskiomi "_... static is a requirement. It should be able to be overridden by instances of an implementing class_" – static methods cannot be overridden. The requirements for the method to be static and to be overridable are contradictory.

Comment: @tuskiomi - What are you using reflection *on*, before you have an instance?

Comment: @AndyThomas the class itself of course, and its associated ASTs

Comment: @tuskiomi - *Which class is that?* (Before you have an instance that identifies one of possibly multiple concrete classes that implements the interface.)

Comment: @AndyThomas any class of a non-primitive type which implements my interface, specifically for the function caller, a call to myType.Deserialize should always get myType.class.

Comment: @tuskiomi - Have you considered using standard Java's `java.io.ObjectInputStream` (on bytes generated by `java.io.ObjectOutputStream`)? These include the object types within the stream of bytes. They're pretty nifty, and resilient to change.

Comment: @AndyThomas I have not... Sadly however, the stream needs to be more language agnostic, and not tied to java. Currently  looking into JSON, YAML, XML, Avro, and others...

Comment: JSON - fasterxml.jackson.  XML - jaxb. Both work with annotations on fields. I think there was more of a learning curve with jaxb. Much easier than reinventing the wheel.

Comment: I'll take a look into this, I think their implementations should help me. Ideally, I don't want to have any annotations required... But you know, seldom is Software Dev. Ideal.

Comment: @tuskiomi - If you're trying to avoid requiring annotations on types you don't control, jaxb's XMLAdapter could help -- you can provide an adapter type that handles marshalling/unmarshalling.

Comment: static interface methods are not inherited. So when you have `class MyType implements Deserializable …` you still can’t write `MyType.deserialize(…);` If `Deserializable` wasn’t an interface but a `class`, you could invoke the method on a subclass and the bytecode would even reflect which class has been used to invoke the method, however, extracting this information would be quite elaborated. That’s not possible with the built-in Reflection.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have run into this with persistence framework development before. You must pass the desired class into the static method.

```
static <T extends Deserializable> T deserialize(byte[] bytes, Class<T> targetType) {
    ReflectionDeserializer rd = new ReflectionDeserializer();
    return rd.Deserialize(bytes, targetType);
}
```

then your RefDes will have something like this

```
    public <T extends Deserializable> T deserialize(byte[] bytes, Class<T> targetType) {
        T target = targetType.newInstance();
        populateFromBytes(target, bytes);
        return target;
}
```

This is obviously not production quality code but the basic idea is how I've achieved this in the past. I might have minor details confused about the `<>` syntax works but this is how I solved this problem for my current project.

Answer (score 3):

You mention "I need the method to be static to be overridable by implementing classes"

That is contradictory, static methods can't be overridden. However, I think what you want is to have it `default` so that you provide a basic implementation, that can eventually be overridden by another implementation.

If you do that and you declare an abstract `getClazz()`, you will be able to do as such:

```
public interface Deserializable<T extends Deserializable> {
    default T deserialize(byte[] bytes) {
        ReflectionDeserializer rd = new ReflectionDeserializer();
        return rd.Deserialize(bytes, getClazz());
    }

    Class<T> getClazz();
}
```

... So if your class wants to override the `deserialize` it will be able to do so, else it just returns its implementing class and lets the default implementation to do the job for it.

Comment: That was my next approach. I think that  it's the way I'll go

Comment: This is not a bad approach - you could for example do `new Cat().populateFrom(bytes);` or something similar with this paradigm although mandating a default constructor has issues of its own...

Answer (score 2):

You might want to consider a different approach to this problem, where Deserializable becomes a generic class holding type T, and has a method that deserializes and returns type T

```
public class Deserializable<T> {


public <T> T deserialize(byte[] bytes) {
    ReflectionDeserializer rd = new ReflectionDeserializer(T.getClass());
    return rd.Deserialize(bytes);
}


   }
```

So whenever you'd want to deserialize your Cat object you'd just do

```
return new Deserializable<Cat>().deserialize(bytes);
```

You won't have to sort of redundantly state Cat twice like in this example

```
return Cat.deserialize(bytes, Cat.class)
```